# Something similar to hull.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I need to do something similar to **[hull.io](http://hull.io)**

For example my user enters this in html:

```
<div data-test-component="hello@test" data-test-provider="test"> </ div>
```

So my script should look for it and render the right content.

I did a little experiment :

```
if ($('div').date('test-component') == "hello@test") {
     $ (document).find("[data-test-component = 'hello @ test']").html("Hello World")
}
```

It works, but do not think that is the best way.
In addition to needing several IFs and does not work with multiple elements.

I would like to help with this. Any guidelines, a way forward.

Comment: Just a question, do you always leave a space between your jquery . html . find? I have never seen that done. Shouldnt . date be data?

Comment: No. I did the experiments on jsFiddle and added that these spaces.

Comment: Ok, but I think your "date" needs to be "data"

Answer (score 0):

Hull.js is built on top of Aura.js, that offers the component system to do this.

You can have a look at the source here:
https://github.com/aurajs/aura

This might be what you want to use ultimately, since it handles instanciation and cleanup of the components that are